# When is it sometimes useful to defining object types to mirror instance-bound methods as static utility functions on the constructor?

Tags: javascript, static

I am a beginner to JavaScript and currently going through the ***The Complete Reference 3rd Edition by Thomas A. Powell , Fritz Schneider***.

I am on the way to learning ***Class Properties***.

I quote an extract from the same book.
It is also sometimes useful when defining ***object types*** to ***mirror instance-bound*** methods as ***static utility functions*** on the ***constructor***. For instance, ***String.prototype.trim()*** is the ***string instance method*** that operates on the *instance* it is called from. However, a ***static utility function*** such as ***String.trim()*** could be defined that takes as its only parameter the string instance it should operate on:

```
if(typeof String.trim == "undefined"){
                String.trim = function(str){
                    alert("Here!");
                    return str.trim();
                }
}

var test = "             The International Jew          ";
alert(test.trim());                                        // The International Jew 
alert(String.trim("          The International Jew"));     // The International Jew
```

I find myself really confused at what use does the above feature gives me and what will actually prompt me to do these kind of transformation from ***some instance method*** to ***static utility function***?
Kind guide me in understanding to this concept as I am a newbie into the programming world.

Comment: lets you do stuff like ["a ", " b ", "c"].map(String.trim) instead of ["a ", " b ", "c"].map(Function.call.bind("".trim))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason I've used a static method instead of an instance method is to handle null/undefined objects. If you use an instance method, you'll always have to wrap your trim calls everywhere

```
if (typeof str == "string") {
    str = str.strim();
} else {
    str = ""; // If you want this
}
```

Whereas, if you have a static method, callers can safely give it a null/undefined object.

```
String.trim = function(str){        
    return typeof str == 'string' ? str.trim() : '';
}

var str;
// String.trim can handle the undefined object
str = String.trim(str);
```

Also, as dandavis mentioned, you could pass that `String.trim` as a callback to functions like `forEach` and `map` without having to specify what `this` is.

```
var trimmed = [" a ", " b ", "c "].map(String.trim);
```

However, note that it's only possible because our static `String.trim` doesn't use `this`, but you may find that some use `this` from a static method to refer to the constructor and in that case you would need to bind it.

For example:

```
String.doubleTrim = function(str) {
    var trimmed = this.trim();
    return trimmed + trimmmed;
} 
// Error trim is not a function
var doubleTrimmed = [" a ", " b ", "c "].map(String.doubleTrim);
// This is OK
var doubleTrimmed = [" a ", " b ", "c "].map(String.doubleTrim.bind(String));

Note that you could work around the above problem by calling `String.trim()` instead of `this.trim()` but some prefer that because it lets you rename your object from a single place.
```

Comment: What do you mean by wrap the trim calls everywhere? Since iam a beginner, please detailed it. Do edit this in your answer, str = str.strim();

Comment: Depends on what the static method does with null/undefined arguments.

Comment: @Bergi That's the  point, the static method can do a null check, but the instance method can't

Comment: Ah, it's about the *ability* to do that, I see. OP's `String.trim` for example doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.
I think if you are beginner, it is better postponing this part and continuing learning the other parts of JavaScript. However I am gonna answer you.
We use Prototype (or as you said "**instance method** ") when we wanna use or change the base characteristic of an object. We also use **static utility functions** when we wanna utilize the abilities of functions in a type or class.

**For example :** When you wanna give the **"trim"**ing ability of String type to another class (things like inheritance for example) you may use prototype. Also when you wanna change the built-in functionality of a class or method, you can change it through changing the **Prototype**. You can Edit, inherit and utilize the whole characteristic of a type or class with Prototype. You can also add new functionality (method) to a built-in class.

Using Prototype you can Manipulate the whole JavaScript functionality through its object hierarchy. And this is why JavaScript is Amazing.

But when you wanna use the functionality of a function, type or a class, you use the static utility function.

In the below link I've talked about some of these fantastic abilities JavaScript has. However this article is about something bigger, but in the first sections I've talked about some of inspiring JavaScript abilities.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/844789/A-Belly-Dance-in-Holy-Lands-of-MVC-MVP-and-MVVM-Pa#xx4977789xx

Comment: English? It is in English!

Comment: there's no such word as "wanna" in written English.

Comment: Yep! I didn't know I shouldn't use it. Thanks for mentioning